# I lose data every time I go back to my activity?

Tags: android

I have a form activity every Edittext open another activity when I change data and I get it in my activity I lose the others that I have changed them before  . [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp73e.jpg) is initial state and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmhup.jpg) is what I get by changing any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a consistent data model in which to store those values. If it's size isn't larger than 2MB you can make this model Parcelable and seriali. After that you must cache those values either in savedInstanceState, SharedPrefs, singleton (I do not recommend it), or local DB (i.e. sqlite). After doing so, whenever your activity is displayed you should check if you already have a saved value for that field and fill it with that.

Comment: you mean I create a local DB and when all fields are not empty the button is enabled and I can save all the form in my DB , Super

Comment: Yes, that is the best practice for everything, but the most complex. Like I've said, if your model object don't take a lot of memory you can use one of the other methods, which are faster to implement and easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

you can fix this by letting it open another fragment instead of activity and make sure that you dont destroy the activity.

so overall view you gonna have 1 main activity and each edit text will replace fragment view

Comment: You mean I have to change every activity by a fragment and it will solve the problem ?

Comment: You said "every Edittext open another activity", change it to "every Edittext open another fragment" while the main page that hold all of the edittext stays activity.
if you have too much work in those activities and u dont want to change to fragment try to use onSaveInstanceState

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour Flora
An activity is not supposed to be persisted if not displayed. That means it could stay as you left in when returning from another activity but it also may not.
If the system needs to free memory it will destroy the activity and recreate it when the user gets back to it. This is the expected behaviour on Android.

So what you should do is store your data when the activity goes out (in `onPause()` method) and fill your edittexts when the activity goes back in (in `onResume()` method)

Pay also attention that you need to handle what they call configuration change (such as screen rotation) using `onConfigurationChanged()` that allows you to pass some information between the former configuration and the latter for reuse.

Finally you should build your layout according to Android's guidelines (material design) for your UI to look a bit more conventional ;)